# Adding multiple different headers to df in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to read in multiple files and store these files as df in memory, since there are no headers in my csv file, I need to add multiple headers to each df manually. **Each file has different headers.**

What I did is using the if-elif statements, which works but very redundant. Does anyone have any idea how to make it more compact/smart?

```
if file_name == "20210101":
    headers = ["Name","Age","City"]
    df = df.read_csv(data, sep=";"dtype= str, names = headers)

elif file_name == "20210102":
    headers = ["Age","Location","Nation"]
    df = df.read_csv(data, sep=";"dtype= str, names = headers)

elif file_name == "20210103":
    headers = ["Account","Position","Sex"]
    df = df.read_csv(data, sep=";"dtype= str, names = headers)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary mapping filenames to headers.

```
headers = {"20210101": ["Name","Age","City"], ...}
df = pd.read_csv(file_name, names=headers[file_name], ...)
```